# Core Data: Expression tree is too large

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, core-data

I need some help with this method:

```
// deletes all points in database except points with given identifiers
- (void)deleteAllPointsExcept:(NSArray *)safeIdentifiers save:(BOOL)save {
    // create request to fetch all 'doomed' points
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[TSAppDelegate delegate] managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"MapPoint"];
    NSMutableArray *subpredicates = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (NSNumber *identifier in safeIdentifiers) {
        NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"pid!=%@", identifier];
        [subpredicates addObject:pred];
    }
    fetchRequest.predicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:subpredicates];

    // fetch 'em & destroy 'em
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *points = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

    for (TSMapPoint *point in points) {
        [context deleteObject:point];
    }

    // save if requested
    if (save) {
        [[[TSAppDelegate delegate] managedObjectContext] save:NULL];
    }
}
```

It's supposed to purge unneeded MapPoints from my Core Data `NSManagedObjectContext`. It works fine but one day I've received this message:

```
CoreData: error: (1) I/O error for database at ...  SQLite error code:1, 'Expression tree is too large (maximum depth 1000)'
```

I've googled that this happens when the predicate is too long like `WHERE id=1 OR id=2 OR id=3 ...` but I don't know how to work around this. Does anybody have an idea?

Thanks in advance,
Pete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your predicate should be simplified to something like the following

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT (pid IN %@)", safeIdentifiers];
```

Comment: Wow, that looks really elegant. :) Are you positive that it works with SQLite under Core Data on iOS?

Comment: Yup - there is an awful lot of powerful predicates that are more complex than this that work perfectly with SQLite

Comment: Well, I've tried your approach and got: `NSInvalidArgumentException - unimplemented SQL generation for predicate : (pid IN {931, 1023, 2971, 3060})`. Sadly, it seems like this is not available on iOS. What do you think of it?

Comment: I've just made a sample project in iOS that works fine with this. Do you have any more info...

Comment: Turning on sqlite debugging I can see the generated sql for the above (in my sample project) looks like `CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZPID FROM ZA t0 WHERE  NOT ( t0.ZPID IN  (?) )`. Can you provide the updated code

Comment: Sure, here you go: http://pastebin.com/J8AALHQ6. I'm using Xcode 6 with the latest SDK (targetting iOS 8). The Core Data code is basically the default implementation you get when creating new project...

Comment: Well, I've figured it out. The predicate syntax you provided was okay. But I've also modified other methods for different data entities and forgot to change the `pid` (primary key name) in the predicate based on the actual `NSManagedObject` involved (in my model, some objects have `nid` or `sid` instead of `pid`). To conclude, Apple could really make that error message slightly less generic. I've spent half my time looking for a solution to the wrong issue. Thanks again for your input!

Comment: You should look at using something like mogenerator which will generate strings constants of your models keys. This will give you compile time checking which sounds like it could have saved you a chunk of time.

Comment: mogenerator?! Why haven't I heard of that earlier! This tool is priceless. Cheers!

Comment: No problem - to clarify your predicate would most likely change to look something like `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT (%K IN %@)", MapPointAttributes.pid, safeIdentifiers]`

Answer (score 0):

When you have too many identifiers, you cannot use them directly in an SQL command (regardless of whether you're using parameters or not).

You have to write all the IDs into a temporary table, and then use a single predicate that checks that table:

```sql
DELETE FROM PointsTable WHERE pid NOT IN MyTempTable
```

Comment: That is a very systemic approach. However, I've been using Core Data for a while now and never needed to write any SQL. Is that even possible on iOS?

Comment: There are mechanisms to use SQL more or less directly (use the raw SQLite C API, or FMDB, or some other library), but not with CoreData.